# AnyLogic Execution with Jar files - Run Fastest Speed

Tags: java, class, jar, anylogic

I am recently developing software with AnyLogic and I have a question about how to run with the fastest speed from outside.

My current code for running a simulation is like this.

```html
package defaultpackage;

import com.anylogic.engine.Experiment;

import agvver1.*;

public class MyClass{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Simulation thisSim = new Simulation();
  thisSim.run();
  Experiment.State ThisState = thisSim.getState();
  while(!ThisState.equals(Experiment.State.FINISHED)) {
   try
   {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
   catch(InterruptedException ex)
   {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
   ThisState = thisSim.getState();
  }
  
  System.out.println(Main.totalTardy);
 }
}
```

It is not so efficient but it can produce outputs very slowly.

How can I run it with the fastest speed as I did it in AnyLogic at virtual speed? I found ExperiemntRunFast class but I have no idea how to use it.

Thanks in advance and have a wonderful day!

[Update]
I tried runFast but it still doesn't work. Please see attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbx2f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
thisSim.run();
```

try

```
thisSim.runFast();
```

Should do the trick :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried it but I cannot find the runFast method.

Comment: runFast only exists in the professional version and you are probably using the university researcher one. Run your simulation using the parameter variation experiment with 1 iteration and I'm pretty sure if you use run() it will run as fast as possible anyways (it will use runFast() internally)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Felipe. I am now using the professional version and build it with the license. I will try the parameter variation experiment and update it.

Comment: I think I can resolve the problem if I can use ExperimentRunFast or ExperimentParamVariation instead of Simulation. Can you guide me how to use it? @Felipe