# Using ExperimentRunFast in AnyLogic with external java applications

Tags: java, anylogic

I am recently developing an application with AnyLogic models and I have a problem with using ExperimentRunFast class.

Does anybody know how to use this class? Here is my code with errors.

```
ExperimentRunFast<Main> thisExp = new ExperimentRunFast<Main>(true) {

        @Override
        String g() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        State j(boolean arg0) throws Throwable {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Main createRoot(Engine arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }};
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Can you provide a little more background on your end goal in using this class?  In 15 years of doing this, I have only had the need to create a custom experiment class/object a couple of times.  There may be a much simpler way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my previous question, I realized there is no runFast method in my built jar so I want to make a custom experiment to accelerate the speed manually.

Comment: I attached the link of the previous question for your information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551507/anylogic-execution-with-jar-files-run-fastest-speed